# getting records that don't have a corresponding record in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 8.3 and would like to get conversations that don't have a messsage with and index value of 0 based upon the following schema:

```
conversations 
id 

messages 
id 
conversation_id 
index (yes, its named that)
body
```

Would the following sql be sufficient? Or is there a better way?

```
select c.id  from conversations c left join
    messages m on c.id = m.conversation_id and m.index = 0 where m.id is null;
```

I know I could do a subquery but would be slower.

Also, should the `m.index = 0` be in the where phrase?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE conversations; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE messages; for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

that depends on tzhe result you want.

With the `index =  0` in the `JOIN` all you would get conversations that have the `index =  1` also in the result set in addition to the conversation without any messages

In the `WHERE`  clause with an `OR` you would get too many results as conversations with index = 0 would be kept.

With an `AND` in the `WHERE` you would get no results at all as both conditions can never be true.

Removing the `INDEX = 0` in the `ON` clause, would only show you all conversations that have no messages at all.

So the choice what to do , depends as always what result you want to get

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
    FROM conversations AS c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1 FROM messages AS m
                    WHERE m.conversation_id = c.id
                      AND m.index = 0
                      );
```